# Why can I not choose the "Sign in with Apple" Capability in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, capability, sign-in-with-apple

I uploaded a screenshot of the capabilities I can choose.

Has that something to do with the Apple Development Programm?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouHi2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Sign in with Apple require Apple Developer Program membership (which is not free).

Here you can see all available capabilities for a given account type: [Supported capabilities (iOS)](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev21218dfd6)

Comment: oh boy thanks for that quick answer. That clears things up. Thx bud <3